# Are we losing tag wikis?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

I thought I'd written a longer description for [desert](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desert) but this disappeared (thought someone might have deleted it as too long winded),  but I'm pretty certain I wrote a tag wiki (long and short) for [tomatoes](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomatoes) and it has complete gone!

The only thing I can think of is that I could have written it for [tomato](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomato) and the synonym creation deleted it?

Answer (score 6):

You're correct, the creation of [tomatoes](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomatoes) and the subsequent merging of [tomato](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomato) as its synonym "orphaned" the wiki. Merging tags does these and it needs to be fixed manually (these slipped my radar).

Here's the entire list of "orphaned" wikis that were caused by tag merges.

1. [Orchid wiki](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/872/revisions), [excerpt](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/873/revisions)
2. [Pepper wiki](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/213/revisions), [excerpt](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/214/revisions)
3. [Tomato wiki](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/847/revisions), [excerpt](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/848/revisions)

Please feel free to edit these in again to the respective master tags. As you were the original author who put in effort into these, it's only fair that you get the credit for the edit. Also, while you're at it, a picture for each from wikipedia might be neat too... something along the lines of the [wiki](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/eggplant/info) for [eggplant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eggplant).

---

I'm pretty sure your long description for [desert](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desert) is a mirage (sorry, couldn't resist!), as the  [revision history](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/1006/revisions) shows you as the only author :). Nothing has been removed/deleted.

Comment: I've re-added the orchid and tomato, but it looks like pepper was already there. I could probably get a herbarium photo of *hexalectris* for the orchids - but it probably isn't the most appropriate (it has never been cultivated, so more of a botanical subject rather than horticultural)

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that where a tag is pruned due to low use the wiki text would also be lost? We seem to have 3 questions with the [desert](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desert)  tag, but perhaps there were fewer at some point when the text was first added?

Comment: If the desert tag was removed after the wiki was created, then re-applied later, that could also result in the wiki being lost. However, I can confirm that that's not the case, because if it were, it would show up as "orphaned wiki" in the moderator tools.